# Finding the Reading Rate

Tags: problem-solving

**Part 1:**
If you read 15 minutes per day every day and end up reading 12 books of 200 pages each in 1 year, what is your reading rate in pages per minute?

**Part 2:**
If you increase your reading speed so that each page takes you 30 seconds less than it did before and you begin reading 20 minutes per day, how many 200 page books can you now read in a year?

I know how to answer the first part of the question. I have 
15 min * 365 days = 5,475 min/yr. and
12 books * 200 pages= 2400 pages so 2400/5745 equals 0.438 pgs/min.

On the second part is where I am confused. I know that multiplying 20 min per day * 365 days= 7300 min/1 year, but I am unsure of where to go from here to find how many 200 page books are read in 1 year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your 0.438 pages/minute is 60/0.438 =~137 seconds per page.

So if you read each page 30 seconds faster you only need 107 seconds per page.

And you have correctly calculated you will now be reading 7300 minutes or 7300*60=438000 seconds per year.

Can you do the rest?

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1-**

total minute(one year) = 15 X 365
no of pages read in one year = 12 x 200 = 1200

number of page read in one minute = no of pages read in one year/total minute(one year) = 2400/5475= .4383

ie 1 minute - .4383 page

ie 60 sec  - .4383 page

time for 1 page 60/.4383 = 136.89

**Part 2**

Time needed to read a page 30 sec less

ie 136.89 -30 = 106.89.

so number of pages read in 1 sec = 1/106.89

number of pages read in 1 min = 1/106.89 * 60

number of pages read in a day =  1/106.89 * 60 * 20

number of pages read in a year =  1/106.89 * 60 * 20 * 365 = 4097.67 ( ie  1/106.89 * 7300)

number of books = number of pages read in a year/200 = 20.49